# Comparison method violates its general contract - Java

Tags: java, comparable

I understand that there are many answers to this question but I'm still having difficulty with this. I understand the idea of A > B, B > C, so A > C and I believe that what I'm doing is capable of working perfectly fine.

```
public int compareTo(Snake snake) {
    double other=snake.testFitness();
    double tFit = this.testFitness();
    if(tFit < other)
        return 1;
    else if(tFit > other)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how something so simple is able to violate the general contract.

Edit: For those asking for the testFitness() function.

```
public double testFitness() {
    fit += ((this.length - 3)*2);
    fit -= this.blocksTraveled*3;
    return fit;
}
```

Comment: Who says you're violating the contract?

Comment: *I believe that what I'm doing is capable of working perfectly fine.* I believe there is something incorrect in that belief, else you wouldn't have posted this. Unfortunately, I can't quite work out what your question is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @shmosel Java does when I try to run my program for too long :P

Comment: Does `Snake.testFitness()` return a consistent value?

Comment: Yes, Snake.testFitness() is always the same

Comment: Post that method please.

Comment: The reason why I thought that what I was doing should work perfectly fine is because some of the other answers that I have found would be missing some information. I.E. they would forget that if the values were equal the function needs to return 0, etc.

Comment: I just... I just... figured it out.... +=....

Comment: You should also replace your comparison with `Double.compare(other, tFit)` or you risk running into trouble with floating-point precision.

Comment: @MagnusCaligo Rather than beating yourself up about this, chalk it up to learning.  More importantly, ANSWER YOUR OWN QUESTION with a description of the problem.  After the required delay, accept the answer. You can be sure someone else will find it useful at some point in the future, which is the ***whole point of StackOverflow***.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate since this is a nontransitive comparison

Comment: @shmosel That is not correct; there is no problem with floating-point precision.  If you look at the code for `Double.compare`, it starts out `if (d1 < d2) return -1; if (d1 > d2) return 1;`, same as what OP's code is doing.  After that, there's some special code, but not because of precision; the problem is NaNs.  If there is no possibility of NaN, then OP's code is equivalent to using `Double.compare`.

Comment: This duplicate question is probably the wrong one.  There's nothing wrong with the logic of `compareTo` _per se_; the problem is that it doesn't return consistent results given the same objects, because the comparison calls a method that has side effects.